# Distribution of Primes (elementary)

Tags: soft-question, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis, prime-gaps

**Disclaimer**: I'm a High Schooler, with only a knowledge of Elementary Number Theory, Geometry/Trig, and Calculus I.

I'm trying to understand the distribution of prime numbers. I've watched a few videos and read a few papers on the Riemann Hypothesis and Twin Prime gaps. I was amazed by the pattern of primes in the Ulam Spiral and on Polar graphs. However, the mathematical reasoning, intuition and notation involved with these ideas escape me. *Are there any elementary papers, or resources that I can use to understand the distribution of Prime Numbers using the mathematical skill set I have?*

Comment: you might enjoy looking at Apostol's _Introduction to Analytic Number Theory_

Comment: Reading one of the classical references also increases your mathematical skill set you have. Apostol's book is really a good reference for this.

Comment: I can share my experience. I was on 3rd grade in my University with major in Math and I listened to special course for analytic number theory. The subject was given at the end, just because it's not possible to skip it in such as course. And I remember it was most difficult to understand topic in the course. So I do not think you can find some elementary and easy proof for prime distribution (well, well... maybe I am wrong, uh?). On the other hand you can easily understand the idea of distribution and the meaning of n / ln(n), so it depends how deep you want to research the topic.

Comment: Mazur and Stein, Prime Numbers and the Riemann Hypothesis, https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/prime-numbers-and-the-riemann-hypothesis/37616412CC94D2349D63ED18E108E39A

Comment: Tenenbaum & Mendes France, The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution, https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-6/

Comment: Steve Gonek, Three lectures on the Riemann Zeta-Function, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401126

Comment: van der Veen and van de Craats, The Riemann Hypothesis, https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/riemann-hypothesis/0DFAF0F13300ECAEB1CB88F1D635A9A9

Comment: Had a chance to chase down any of these suggestions, DarkRunner?